# Callouts to third party change feed

Tags: rest-api, scheduled-apex, future, queue

I am looking for some advice with the following:

I have a:

1. Scheduled class that runs every 5 minutes that calls a CheckChangeFeed Class
2. The check change feed class looks for a change token, if there has been a change to the token this then calls a class to retrieve the list of changes
3. Once the list of changes has been retrieved each change from the list is then sent out to a last class to handle the change that occurred.

My issue is that each class runs an @future method. This is giving me an error as a future method cannot call another future method.

Does anyone have any suggestions or solutions they have come up with for similar issues?

Comment: You'll need to elaborate. Do you have one scheduled class that is scheduled to run every 5 minutes (can only be done via execute anonymous)?  Or do you have three scheduled classes, each scheduled to run every 15 minutes (also via execute anonymous). PLEASE use [edit] to amend your question. do not add a comment

Comment: This is a design issue. Ask question to yourself, why you need @future? Why you need 3 different classes? Rest of the thing explained in first comment which will prevent the question being answered. This question will be closed very quickly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert your @future methods to the new QueueableApex interface. QueueableApex can be enqueued from @future methods and from other QueueableApex classes.

Comment: I was reading about QueueableApex last night and I think this is what will solve my issue from the sounds of things. I wanted to ask the question first and make sure I am following best practices